# How to get values from radio button values inside different layouts in viewflipper

Tags: android, viewflipper, radio-group

I'm creating a small quiz using view flipper which consist of 4 question and answer. I have used radiobutton and groups for answer the questions. I have used 4 layouts in viewflipper for 4 question and answer now my problem is that I can get value from first question which is in 1st layout but I can't get the answers from other questions which is in other layouts. anyone help me with this out. I have posted my code below

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Comptest extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    //urls

    String url="**************************.php";

    //json array

    JSONArray jarray;

    //Array list

    ArrayList<String> c_alquestion = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alcorrectanswer = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alwronganswer1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alwronganswer2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alwronganswer3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alwronganswer4 = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> c_alwronganswer5 = new ArrayList<String>();

    //quiz array list

    ArrayList<String> q_question=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> ansl=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wans1=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wans2=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wans3=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wans4=new ArrayList<String>();

    int count=0;

    //PagerAdapter tst_padapter;

    int id1,id2,id3,id4;

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    Button Next, Previous;

    Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right;

    //Textview questions

    TextView qst1,qst2,qst3,qst4;
    //Radio button

    RadioButton rb1_1,rb1_2,rb1_3,rb1_4,rb1_5,rb1_6;
    RadioButton rb2_1,rb2_2,rb2_3,rb2_4,rb2_5,rb2_6;
    RadioButton rb3_1,rb3_2,rb3_3,rb3_4,rb3_5,rb3_6;
    RadioButton rb4_1,rb4_2,rb4_3,rb4_4,rb4_5,rb4_6;
    RadioButton rb5_1,rb5_2,rb5_3,rb5_4,rb5_5,rb5_6;

    RadioGroup rag1,rag2,rag3,rag4;

    RadioButton rab1,rab2,rab3,rab4;

     private float initialXpoint;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.comp);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);

    rag1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioanswer);

    intit();

    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

    slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);

    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);

    Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);

    Previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousbtn);



     Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                id1 = rag1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                rab1=(RadioButton)findViewById(id1);
                System.out.println("1nd question answer"+rab1.getText());
                    count++;
                    switch(count)
                    {

                    case 1:

                        temp.clear();
                        temp.add(c_alcorrectanswer.get(1));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer1.get(1));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer2.get(1));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer3.get(1));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer4.get(1));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer5.get(1));

                        Collections.shuffle(temp);
                        rb2_1.setText(temp.get(0));
                        rb2_2.setText(temp.get(1));
                        rb2_3.setText(temp.get(2));
                        rb2_4.setText(temp.get(3));
                        rb2_5.setText(temp.get(4));
                        rb2_6.setText(temp.get(5));



                        //viewFlipper.showNext();
                        break;

                    case 2:

                        temp.clear();
                        temp.add(c_alcorrectanswer.get(2));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer1.get(2));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer2.get(2));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer3.get(2));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer4.get(2));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer5.get(2));

                        Collections.shuffle(temp);
                        rb3_1.setText(temp.get(0));
                        rb3_2.setText(temp.get(1));
                        rb3_3.setText(temp.get(2));
                        rb3_4.setText(temp.get(3));
                        rb3_5.setText(temp.get(4));
                        rb3_6.setText(temp.get(5));

                        //viewFlipper.showNext();
                        break;

                    case 3:

                        temp.clear();
                        temp.add(c_alcorrectanswer.get(3));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer1.get(3));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer2.get(3));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer3.get(3));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer4.get(3));
                        temp.add(c_alwronganswer5.get(3));

                        Collections.shuffle(temp);
                        rb4_1.setText(temp.get(0));
                        rb4_2.setText(temp.get(1));
                        rb4_3.setText(temp.get(2));
                        rb4_4.setText(temp.get(3));
                        rb4_5.setText(temp.get(4));
                        rb4_6.setText(temp.get(5));

                        //viewFlipper.showNext();
                        break;
                    }


                    viewFlipper.showNext();

                    /*id2 = rag2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    rab2=(RadioButton)findViewById(id2);
                    System.out.println("2nd question answer"+rab2.getText());

                    id3 = rag3.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    rab3=(RadioButton)findViewById(id3);
                    System.out.println("2nd question answer"+rab3.getText());

                    id4 = rag4.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    rab4=(RadioButton)findViewById(id4);
                    System.out.println("2nd question answer"+rab4.getText());
            */      

            }
        });

            Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        });

    new Dailytask().execute();

    Collections.shuffle(temp);
    System.out.println("<-----going to set----->"+temp);
    /*rb1_1.setText(temp.get(0));
    rb1_2.setText(temp.get(1));
    rb1_3.setText(temp.get(2));
    rb1_4.setText(temp.get(3));
    rb1_5.setText(temp.get(4));*/
}


private void intit()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    qst1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.c_qst);
    qst2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.c_qst2);
    qst3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.c_qst3);
    qst4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.c_qst4);


    rag1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioanswer);
    rag2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioanswer2);
    rag3=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioanswer3);
    rag4=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioanswer4);

    rb1_1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_1);
    rb1_2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_2);
    rb1_3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_3);
    rb1_4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_4);
    rb1_5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_5);
    rb1_6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn1_6);

    rb2_1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_1);
    rb2_2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_2);
    rb2_3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_3);
    rb2_4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_4);
    rb2_5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_5);
    rb2_6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2_6);

    rb3_1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_1);
    rb3_2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_2);
    rb3_3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_3);
    rb3_4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_4);
    rb3_5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_5);
    rb3_6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3_6);

    rb4_1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_1);
    rb4_2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_2);
    rb4_3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_3);
    rb4_4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_4);
    rb4_5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_5);
    rb4_6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4_6);

    /*rb5_1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    rb5_2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    rb5_3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    rb5_4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    rb5_5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
*/}


/*@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
    switch (touchevent.getAction())
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXpoint = touchevent.getX();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalX = touchevent.getX();
        if (initialXpoint > finalX)
        {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
            break;
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
        else
        {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
            break;
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
*/

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*id=c_radioanswergroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    c_radioanswerButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);

    System.out.println("answer--"+c_radioanswerButton.getText());
    */

}



private class Dailytask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> 
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();



        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Comptest.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Assessment ...");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        Json j = new Json();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = j.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
    {

        System.out.println("---------------return today test json------------"+json);

        pDialog.dismiss();

        try
        {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
            JSONObject jobj = json.getJSONObject("response");

            jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("YearTest");

            System.out.println("json array length"+jarray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject data = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing JSON item in a Variable

                c_alquestion.add(data.getString("question"));

                c_alcorrectanswer.add(data.getString("correctanswer"));

                c_alwronganswer1.add(data.getString("wronganswer1"));

                c_alwronganswer2.add(data.getString("wronganswer2"));

                c_alwronganswer3.add(data.getString("wronganswer3"));

                c_alwronganswer4.add(data.getString("wronganswer4"));

                c_alwronganswer5.add(data.getString("wronganswer5"));


                System.out.println("question------->"+c_alquestion);
                System.out.println("correct answer------------>"+c_alcorrectanswer);
                System.out.println("wroang ans1------------>"+c_alwronganswer1);

                System.out.println("wroang ans2------------>"+c_alwronganswer2);
                System.out.println("wroang ans3------------>"+c_alwronganswer3);
                System.out.println("wroang ans4------------>"+c_alwronganswer4);

                System.out.println("wroang ans5------------>"+c_alwronganswer5);



            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("<------EXCEPTION------>"+e);
        }

        /*Collections.shuffle(c_alquestion);
        System.out.println("<------------shuffle------>"+c_alquestion);
        */
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            q_question.add(c_alquestion.get(i));

        }
        System.out.println("<-----question list after shuffle------>"+q_question);
        qst1.setText(q_question.get(0));
        qst2.setText(q_question.get(1));
        qst3.setText(q_question.get(2));
        qst4.setText(q_question.get(3));


        temp.add(c_alcorrectanswer.get(0));
        temp.add(c_alwronganswer1.get(0));
        temp.add(c_alwronganswer2.get(0));
        temp.add(c_alwronganswer3.get(0));
        temp.add(c_alwronganswer4.get(0));
        temp.add(c_alwronganswer5.get(0));

        System.out.println("<-----temp data--->"+temp);

        Collections.shuffle(temp);
        rb1_1.setText(temp.get(0));
        rb1_2.setText(temp.get(1));
        rb1_3.setText(temp.get(2));
        rb1_4.setText(temp.get(3));
        rb1_5.setText(temp.get(4));
        rb1_6.setText(temp.get(5));



    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the child id by using getDisplayedChild() method and get the values of views from particular layout or child.